# Calculation of areas between two curves

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a code contain a curve and a line. I know how to fill the areas below and under the line but I need to calculate the areas values of each one.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = 0*x
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True)
ax.plot(x, y1, x, y2, color='black')
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 >= y1, facecolor='green',    interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 <= y1, facecolor='red', interpolate=True)
plt.show()
```

Any help?

Comment: Look at `scipy.integrate.quad`

Comment: You said you know how to "fill the areas".   Does that mean "integrate each function"?  If yes, shouldn't the answer you want be nothing more than simple subtraction?

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from the [`scipy.integrate.quad` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) example for a different function, y = x^2:

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
    return x**2

integrate.quad(f, 0, 4)
# (21.333333333333332, 2.3684757858670003e-13)

print(4**3 / 3.)  # analytical result
# 21.3333333333
```

The result and an error for the numerical calculation is returned.

If you want an exact or symbolic answer, consider [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/calculus.html).  Here is a similar example applied to y = πx^2 (Note: leading underscores were used here to distinguish Sympy objects).

```
import sympy as sym

sym.init_printing()

_x = sym.symbols("x")
_f = sym.pi * _x**2
sym.integrate(_f, (_x, 0, 2))
```

[image]

Apply either of these techniques to your problem.

Comment: what if i don't have the equation of y1 i have only the values of y1[x] ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking given some points, how do fit a line the models y1, i.e. non-linear regression or do you want to connect lines between the points?

Comment: i have some points from y1, and y2 is the linear regression of y1. i want to calculate the all area under y2 and all area above y2.

Comment: y2 is not a regression in your case.  It is a separate line.  The main function is y1.  By understanding how integration works for a sin wave, you should be able to configure the limits of the above examples to determine these answers.

Comment: But how i can determine the x value where y1 is above y2 and y1 is under y2 ?

Comment: Hint: You know the points of intersections.  A set of intersections can define the bounds of an integral. And you can do as many integrations as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **[numerical-integration](/questions/tagged/numerical-integration)**.
There's a bunch of standard methods. As @pylang said they're already implemented in `scipy.integrate.*` . `scipy.integrate.quad` is ***Gaussian quadrature***.